# make a label textbox after click

Tags: javascript, label, edit

i have amount column in a table that shows on web page.

what i want to do is when page open up to show amount as label.

when user clicks on the amount it becomes editable like textbox.

Comment: Could you try rewording your question, and maybe providing some sample HTML? It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this (using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
<span id="amount">3.25</span>
<input id="amount_entry" name="amount" style="display:none;"></input>

$('#amount').click(function() {
    $('#amount').css('display', 'none');
    $('#amount_entry')
        .val($('#amount').text())
        .css('display', '')
        .focus();
});

$('#amount_entry').blur(function() {
    $('#amount_entry').css('display', 'none');
    $('#amount')
        .text($('#amount_entry').val())
        .css('display', '');
});
```

Sample demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LFgxr/

Comment: exactly like this. thanks for your help my friend

Comment: but one important thing is that when i will submit this page.will i be able to get the value of label??

Comment: I have added `name="amount"` to the input, and it should post as `amount` to the server.